# Как удалить контрольные точки windows?

Tags: c#, wmi

За основу взят [этот](https://oomake.com/question/77785) код, я его немного переделал.

Создал метод который возвращает все контрольные точки восстановления

```
public static string GetPoint()
{
  var Results = new StringBuilder();
  try
  {
    using (ManagementObjectCollection searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\DEFAULT", "SELECT * FROM SystemRestore").Get())
    {
       foreach (ManagementBaseObject collection in searcher)
       {
          string description = collection["description"].ToString(); // Имя контрольной точки
          string sequencenumber = ((uint)collection["sequencenumber"]).ToString(); // Номер контрольной точки

           Results.AppendLine(sequencenumber);
       }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
  return Results.ToString();
}
```

На выходе получаю порядковые номера контрольных точек **Windows**: `62`, `73`,

Но вот как мне удалить их через массив не понимаю, попробовал прогнать через `foreach`

```
foreach (var test in GetPoint()) // var возвращает char
{
   SRRemoveRestorePoint(test); // показывает только 2 
}
```

но это не помогло. 
Что исправить нужно?

[**UPD**]

Если просто записать `SRRemoveRestorePoint(62);` то точка восстановления удаляется нормально.

Comment: char - не int. И вообще, как тебе такое писать в голову пришло??

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос следующим способом:
Взял из [этого](https://gist.github.com/kek-Sec/23604e7b3af41592a934dc41f836c17a) примера

Удаляет все контрольные точки, проверил.

P.S: *Для запуска требуются права Администратора.*

```
public static void GetPoint()
{
  string[] sequencenums = new string[100];
  int c = 0;
  try
  {
    using (ManagementObjectCollection searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\DEFAULT", "SELECT * FROM SystemRestore").Get())
    {
      foreach (ManagementBaseObject collection in searcher)
      {
        string description = collection["description"].ToString(); // Имя контрольной точки
        string sequencenumber = ((uint)collection["sequencenumber"]).ToString(); // Номер контрольной точки
        sequencenums[c] = sequencenumber; c++;
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
  while (c >= 0)
  {
     int test = SRRemoveRestorePoint(Convert.ToInt32(sequencenums[c]));
     Console.WriteLine($"Point {test} deleted successfully!");
     c--;
  }
}
```

Если у Вас есть предложения по улучшению, давайте)

[**UPD**]

[SRRemoveRestorePoint](http://filelog.net/func/SRRemoveRestorePoint)

Так же нашёл решение ещё одно, решил просто создать цикл `for` и прогнать в нём.
Самое интересное что такой способ даже не вызывает никаких исключений и можно использовать спокойно в отдельном  потоке.

```
// Запуск от Администратора.
public static void DeletePoint()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
     SRRemoveRestorePoint(i);
  }
}
```